# what quotes to use in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

I am aware of the differences between "", '', and ``. But, which one is best / standard? My project right now has a mix of all the three but I would like to know, if a good coder was to review my project, which quotes would they wish to see?

Answer (score -7):

You should NEVER use "" or ``. You should always use '', and concatenate strings instead of using ${} with the `. This is the standard. Never use the other two.

Comment: This answer really lacks reasoning. You say to never use double quotes or backticks, but don't explain why. You also specify something is the standard: but what standard is that? I just don't think this answer is helpful as is, it just appears to be throwing out some opinions without anything to substantiate it.

Comment: If they should never be used, why are they part of the language? `\`` strings (template literals) were just recently added. Surely there was a reason for that? Maybe at least two good reasons?